# Example about how set a Hive property from within a Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, hortonworks-data-platform, bigdata

I need a quick example of how to change a property in hive using a query, for instance, I would like to change the property 'mapred.reduce.tasks' so, how to perform this change within a query.

I'm training my self for HDPCD exam and one of the goals in the exam is 'Set a Hadoop or Hive configuration property from within a Hive query' So I suppose that it's not the same as performing in hive console something like:

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=2;
```

Comment: It sounds to me like the 'set...' example you show is the answer they are looking for. This page (https://hadoopsters.net/2015/12/07/preparing-for-the-hdpcd-exam-data-analysis/) seems to confirm that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change Hadoop and Hive configuration variable you need to use `set` in the hive query.
The change made will be applicable only to that query session

`set -v` prints all Hadoop and Hive configuration variables.

```
SET mapred.reduce.tasks=XX // In Hadoop 1.X
SET mapreduce.job.reduces=XX // In Hadoop 2.X (YARN)
```

`reset` in query resets the configuration to the default values

Comment: So, the example I made in my question is the answer too isnt it?